# nestedscrollview large height image not shows in image-view android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to shows a image in image-view from draw-able folder. image size is 400 k only but height is too long. 400*3777 (width*height) Just want to show that image. If i use another image that shows perfectly.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="@color/apps_color"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/support_faq"

                />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Give height to image view like 400dp or any other.

Comment: If i fixed height image not look good

Comment: Then remove nested scrollview.

Comment: Without scrollview image not shows only i can shows screen size image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use same image but reduce the resolution of that image . SO from 400 x 3777 to you can use 400 x 1080 .

Comment: How can I reduce that 400*3777 (width*height) image.

Comment: you need to use other image editor like photoshop or something . you can also use paint .(if you're working on windows)

Comment: Bitmap yourBitmap;
  Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourBitmap, newWidth, newHeight, true);

Comment: Ok I understand will be use textview only as in my image there are lots of text and color if i reduce height and wight text will be looks so small. its better to make  a large layout design.

Comment: its upon you . according to your image and your requirements . Happy Coding

Comment: if your issue has been solved , you can accept this answer , so we can close this topic @Tariqul